# Simple way to test rails on ubuntu surver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, server, hosting

I have an app and wanted to quickly get it running on an AWS ubuntu server.

Without installing anything extra (like in this tutorial http://www.frontcoded.com/rails-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu.html) is there a way to achieve this using `rails server` and then accessing the server address in the browser?

I want this because it would be nice to know a quick way to get an app up for testing and showing friends,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple deployment process, use [Heroku](http://heroku.com).

To make your rails app running on ec2 instance, you need to at least configure nginx and install ruby.

Comment: Ah ok. So that tutorial was oversimplified and misleading, see the end of the page